# Linear Regression (R) : Can we change the hypothesis testing method from t-test to z-test?

Tags: r, regression

I ran a linear regression example in R and as a result got the following summary:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Income ~ Age + Education + Gender, data = income_input)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-37.340  -8.101   0.139   7.885  37.271 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7.26299    1.95575   3.714 0.000212 ***
Age          0.99520    0.02057  48.373  < 2e-16 ***
Education    1.75788    0.11581  15.179  < 2e-16 ***
Gender      -0.93433    0.62388  -1.498 0.134443    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 12.07 on 1496 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6364,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6357 
F-statistic:   873 on 3 and 1496 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

As you can see, we get the t-values. In this case, how can i change my type of test from t to z?

Furthermore, both t and z tests assume normality. So what if i want to run the Wilcox Test?

Comment: If you want to do a z-test then the variables of the residuals must be known, from the moment you estimate $\sigma$ from your data the t-test must be used.  If you are sure to know $\sigma$ then the estimated coefficient $\hat{\beta}_i$ divided by $\sigma$ can be used to find the p-value (using a standard normal distribution).

Answer (score 1):

The $t$-statistic given is the same as the $z$-statistic that you would get if you assumed a known variance, so you can use `pnorm()` to convert it to a $p$-value. The $t$-test will usually be better calibrated, so this is typically a bad idea unless you are doing it for compatibility with some other software.

> Furthermore, both t and z tests assume normality. So what if i want to
> run the Wilcox Test?

The Wilcoxon test is for two-group comparison. It doesn't apply to regression models, nor is it easily extended to apply.

The closest analogue is probably a score test in a proportional odds model, as provided by the `orm()` function in the `rms` package. If your model had a single binary predictor, that test would be equivalent to a Wilcoxon rank-sum test.

Answer (score -1):

For z-score, you can manually enter the formula based on your current results.
If `x` is the vector with raw data then usually `scale x` is a vector with standardized scores.

You can enter it manually this way: `(x-mean(x))/sd(x)`

Comment: Actually i'm asking about the z-statistic for hypothesis testing rather than the value itself. That would change the corresponding p-value.